# Ban IP address based on X number of unsuccessful sql server login attempts?

Tags: windows, sql-server, powershell

Is it possible to expand on the idea presented in

[Ban IP address based on X number of unsuccessful login attempts?](https://serverfault.com/questions/233222/ban-ip-address-based-on-x-number-of-unsuccessful-login-attempts)

to encompass IP addresses for repeated failed sql server login attempts?

There are log entries in the Application log for each failed attempt.
Source = MSSQLSERVER
EventID = 18456 and 18452

EDIT 1:In Michael Khalili's response, the `#Select Ip addresses that has audit failure` powershell section could be replaced by:

```
#Select Ip addresses that has audit failure
$l = Get-EventLog -LogName 'Application' -InstanceId 3221243928 -After $DT | Select-Object @{n='CLIENT';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[-1]} }
```

This gives a list from the application log but isn't in a similar format leading into the `#Get ip addresses, that have more than x wrong logins` powershell section.

I'm not confident the selection is proper.

Comment: If you're talking login attempts from the internet, I think a better solution would be to stop exposing a database server directly to the Internet.

Comment: apologies in advance for the post formatting.  i'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: I tried to turn off tracking protection in case it was blocking some scripts but no change (still ignores single line breaks and code blocks). Thanks longneck for the edit to correct the layout.

Comment: The most common way is to lock the account, using AD Account lockout policies. If there is an threat actor brute forcing you shoud stop him before he reaches your machines.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ts_block](https://github.com/EvanAnderson/ts_block). I use it on my win2k3 server to block multi failed ssh attempts and it works great. Just modify config for remote MSSQL connections.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd like to continue with powershell though.

Comment: We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This may theoretically answer the question however, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this...I get the previous idea, your line to retrieve the data and performed some mod...here is...

(And sorry for my dirty code..It was my 1st time working with PS)

```
$DT = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1) 

$l = Get-EventLog -LogName 'Application' -InstanceId 3221243928 -After $DT | Select-Object @{n='CLIENT';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[-1]} }
$g = $l | group-object -property CLIENT  | where {$_.Count -gt 10} | Select -property Name

$fw = New-Object -ComObject hnetcfg.fwpolicy2 

$ar = $fw.rules | where {$_.name -eq 'Blocks'} 

$arRemote = $ar.RemoteAddresses -split(',') 

$w = $g | where {$_.Name.Length -gt 1 -and  !($arRemote -contains $_.Name + '/255.255.255.255') } 

$x = $w.Name.Replace(" [CLIENT: ","")

$z = $x.Replace("]","")
$h = ""
for($i=0;$i -lt $z.Count;$i++)
{
    $h += $z[$i]
    $h +="/255.255.255.255"
    $h += ","
}
$full = $h + $ar.remoteaddresses
$fullarray = $full.Split(',') 

$newlist = $fullarray | select -uniq

$ips = "";
for($i=0;$i -lt $newlist.Count;$i++)
{
    $ips += $fullarray[$i]
    if($i -lt ($newlist.Count -1))
    {
        $ips +=","
    }
}

$w| %{$ar.remoteaddresses = $ips} # add IPs to firewall rule
```