# Why doesn't this first iptables rule match repeated connection attempts?

Tags: iptables

Trying to mitigate SSH brute-force attacks on my box, I [copied/pasted](https://serverfault.com/a/327054/155703) the following rules into my `iptables` (without really understanding them, I must confess):

```
$> iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Wed Jun 11 15:13:01 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1255:139338]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1099:174390]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH --rsource -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 5 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "[iptables] SSH brute-force "
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 5 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 11 15:13:01 2014
```

To my delight, it works as intended (repeated connections attempts are rejected, while legitimate attempts go through). I since realised that there are other ways to achieve the same effect: [example 1](https://serverfault.com/a/217066/155703), [example 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110453/72113).

I (believe I) understand how the *other* methods work, but I fail to understand how the first rule above matches only "new incoming connections from *untracked* sources".

This contradicts what I understand from [the manual](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html):

> `--set:` This will always return success

**What in this rule makes it *not* match repeated connection attempts?** I assume the first rule does *not* match repeated connection attempts, otherwise the subsequent rules would never kick in.

I would expect *any* new incoming connection to match this rule.

In the other examples, they don't mention the target `-j ACCEPT`:

```
-A INPUT (...) -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH --rsource
```

So perhaps my question could be rephrased:

**Is the `-j` option useless when used together with `--set --name [some_name]`?**

---

As requested, here are the results of `iptables -L -n -v` (ssh'ing from/to localhost, since I only have remote access right now):

**Initial state:**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 895 packets, 101K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   18  1080 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 state NEW recent: SET name: SSH side: source
   19   962 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 recent: CHECK seconds: 60 hit_count: 5 TTL-Match name: SSH side: source LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[iptables] SSH brute-force "
   19   962 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 5 TTL-Match name: SSH side: source reject-with tcp-reset

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 776 packets, 119K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**After attempt #4:**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1040 packets, 121K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   22  1320 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 state NEW recent: SET name: SSH side: source
   19   962 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 recent: CHECK seconds: 60 hit_count: 5 TTL-Match name: SSH side: source LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[iptables] SSH brute-force "
   19   962 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 5 TTL-Match name: SSH side: source reject-with tcp-reset

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 911 packets, 141K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**After attempt #5 (which was rejected):**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1063 packets, 122K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   23  1380 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 state NEW recent: SET name: SSH side: source
   21  1054 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 recent: CHECK seconds: 60 hit_count: 5 TTL-Match name: SSH side: source LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[iptables] SSH brute-force "
   21  1054 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 5 TTL-Match name: SSH side: source reject-with tcp-reset

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 933 packets, 144K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**Log of the "attack":**

```
Jun 11 15:07:02 [hostname_hidden] kernel: [249278.516231] [iptables] SSH brute-force IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=59245 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=36129 DPT=22 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
Jun 11 15:07:18 [hostname_hidden] kernel: [249294.514964] [iptables] SSH brute-force IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=59246 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=36129 DPT=22 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, not least because of the sarcasm quotes around *"it works"*.  Does your two-line recipe work or not?  Because the question completely changes depending on the answer to that.

Comment: Yes it works as intended (repeated connection attempts are rejected while legitimate connections go through). I'll try to rephrase.

Comment: @MadHatter Okay I think I asked the question the wrong way around, please bear with me.

Comment: Question rephrased so as to make sense.

Comment: OK, now I get it (I think!).  Could you show us the evidence that it works as intended (ie, that rate-limiting cuts in)?

Comment: Well, when I try to ssh into the box several times in a row, the fifth attempt is rejected with "Connection reset by peer". I actually have another line with `LOG` as target, and the last attempt does appear in the logs.

Comment: I ask to see because the devil is often in the details: for example, do your `LOG`ging lines do so with different `--log-prefix`es, so you can be sure that the log comes from the line you think?  The output of `iptables -L -n -v` after the fourth successful attempt, and after the fifth attempt (first rejected one) would be most helpful, too.  I ask because I'm testing the same thing, now, and I don't see the behaviour you see.

Comment: @MadHatter Updated with my actual `iptables` configuration, as well as the requested logs. Still trying to figure out how to read this. Also, added the *uncut* output of `iptables-save`. Perhaps the initial `*filter` is meaningful after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the answer is in the packet counts, and the details of the rules.  Specifically, with attempt 5, the counts on **both** rulesets (the `ACCEPT`, and the `LOG`/`REJECT` pair) are incremented.

I suspect that with attempt 5, the **initial** `SYN` packet matches the `ACCEPT` rule, and is both `ACCEPT`ed and bumps the counts.  But because the count has been incremented by that `ACCEPT`ed `SYN` packet, **subsequent** packets in that newly-established connection now match the later `LOG`/`REJECT` pair, and thus are rejected.  The logs help to confirm this view, as you will see that neither `REJECT`ed packet has the `SYN` flag set.

Comment: I understand that *all rules* must match, therefore something else is *preventing* this rule to match. Subsequent repeated connection attempts are NEW, aren't they? So which part of the rule matches the fact that the connection attempt must not be a "repeated" one?

Comment: Answer edited to address this, in the light of the new data provided.

Comment: This definitely makes sense. I just realised I get "Address family not supported by protocol" from/to localhost, whereas I get "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" from a remote host or from localhost to [IP address]. I need to think this through, but it seems to confirm your explaination.

Comment: Maybe not. But after removing `-j ACCEPT`, I now get a regular "Connection refused" from [remote|localhost] to [IP address], so you definitely nailed it. (I still get "not supported by protocol" from/to localhost, and I hope I will figure out the reason).